# Extract GET URIs or their responses from Wireshark capture to separate file(s)

Tags: http, video-streaming, wireshark, network-monitoring

### Issue

I use Wireshark to capture a HTTP video stream and I've use the following filter to filter out the relevant GET requests.

```
http.request.uri contains "identifier" && http.request.method == "GET" && ip.addr == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

### Questions

1. Is it possible to extract all get GET URLs to separate a .txt file?
2. Or is possible to extract the raw response packets (without the header) which match the filter above to separate files so that I have a bunch of individual video files eventually?

I hope I made myself clear enough ;-)

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

While this may be doable with Wireshark, it is orders of magnitude easier with [Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org).

## Extracting URIs

Simply run it with your trace file:

```
bro -r <trace>
```

This invocation generates a bunch of log files in the current directory. The one you are interested in is `http.log`. You can filter the output to obtain only the GET requests:

```
bro-cut id.orig_h id.resp_h method host uri < http.log | awk '$3 == "GET"'
```

Example output:

```
192.168.1.104   212.96.161.238  GET update.avg.com  /softw/90/update/avg9infowin.ctf
192.168.1.104   77.67.44.206    GET backup.avg.cz   /softw/90/update/u7avi1777u1705ff.bin
192.168.1.104   198.189.255.75  GET aa.avg.com  /softw/90/update/u7iavi2511u2510ff.bin
192.168.1.104   77.67.44.206    GET backup.avg.cz   /softw/90/update/x8xplsb2_118c8.bin
```

As you can see, the last two columns make up the full URL. To remove the space in-between, you could use awk to concatenate the last two fields.

## Extracting Files

Note: the upcoming Bro 2.1 release will have major improvements for file extractions. Until then, you can extract all files from a HTTP stream by specifying the MIME type of the files to store:

```
bro -r <trace> 'HTTP::extract_file_type = /video\/avi/'
```

Bro sniffs the MIME type of a HTTP body and if it matches the regular expression `/video\/avi/`, it creates a file with the prefix `http-item`. You can change the prefix name by redefining the `HTTP::extraction_prefix` variable.

Comment: I'm new to bro. How do I create a trace file? A quick look at the documentation doesn't provide an answer to me. The question is in the scope of a Wireshark capture (PCAP) so it would be useful to include how to create a bro trace file from a PCAP.

Comment: Wireshark also uses libpcap to get packets, either from a trace or from a live interface. For reproducibility, one typically creates a trace file as opposed to sniffing from an interface. That's independent of Bro/Wireshark. On UNIX systems, just use `tcpdump`. On Windows, you can also use Wireshark to save packets from an interface in file, then you have a trace. By the way, Bro can also read traffic from a live interface when passing it `bro -i <iface>`.

Comment: Ah, so you mean a trace file is just a pcap file? That's confusing if you don't know that. ;-)

Comment: You got it. The community often uses the words interchangeably, with PCAP being the de-facto standard for network traffic traces.

Comment: @mavam the app name is now "zeek" likely. Not "bro". Can you please mention here and in the answer how to get trace file about which you are writing?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Question 1:-

Use tshark utility. Easy to install, just "**sudo apt-get install tshark**"

The command I use for the same is :-

```
tshark  -R 'tcp.port==80 && (http.request.method == "GET" || http.request.method=="HEAD" || http.request.method=="POST" )'  -r eth2uplink_00001    -Tfields -e ip.dst -e http.request.method -e http.request.full_uri > requests_eth2_00001
```

Refer to all the Wireshark display filters here :-
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/

This is way better approach than using Bro, Because, Bro is very complicated to install as it has specific dependencies and they could hardly be met.

I currently don't have a solution for question 2, but I believe it can be constructed something on similar lines.
Following options may be useful to what you are trying.

***-O            Only show packet details of these protocols, comma
                           separated***

**-x                       add output of hex and ASCII dump (Packet Bytes)**
You could refer tshark --help for more info.

Hope this helps.
Thanks.