# Tool for monitoring network request (not packets) on mac os

Tags: http, networking, request, firebug, wireshark

Firebug has output like what I need but I have to monitor a little server and not a web page load. I tried Wireshark but the output is not very useful since wading through all the packets to put a request together is very time consuming and complicated. I would like to quickly see all the request sent and received. So I would like a tool that has output like Firebug but can monitor request sent from any application like Wireshark. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: [Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org) can do that easily: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11081321/1170277. It's not a GUI application, though.

Comment: Can't you log these requests on the server itself? Most http servers have flexible logging options.

Answer (score 0):

I am using fiddler, really useful tool for web developer :)
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Fiddler does not run natively on Mac OS.