# Filter for ONLY initial GET request in tshark or tcpdump. Including HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: http, https, wireshark, packet-sniffers, tcpdump

I want to be able to filter for ONLY initial GET request using tshark or tcpdump. This has to work for both HTTP and HTTPS traffic. This is what I currently have...

```
tshark -R '(http.request.method == "GET") && (http.request.uri =="/")'
```

This returns GET request for all HTTP traffic but does nothing when I go to HTTPS sites. Any ideas would be great! thanks

Comment: Unless you supply the private key of the server certificate to your monitoring box, you're out out luck with HTTPS. For unencrypted traffic, you may also consider [the Bro approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11081321/1170277) to extract HTTP data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"https" is HTTP-over-SSL/TLS-over-TCP.  The "SSL/TLS" part means that the raw TCP segments contain *encrypted* data, so they don't, for example, contain the string "GET" (unless, by pure accident, something happens to encrypt to a sequence of bytes that includes 0x47 0x45 0x54).

This means that any program doing filtering will have to *decrypt* the data in the stream.  tcpdump doesn't support decrypting SSL/TLS; [Wireshark/TShark can, in some cases, be configured to decrypt SSL/TLS traffic, if you can supply it with the information required to do so](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).